# Trouble creating a navigation menu

Tags: html, css, tabs, navigation

I'm sure this is an easy one but I just can't figure it out. I have this HTML 
(http://jsfiddle.net/qzr3X/)

```
<div id="wrapper">
<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second Tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Third Tab</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content"></div>
```

​

and CSS:

```
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul#tabs {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul#tabs li  {
    float: left;
}
ul#tabs li a {
    z-index: 99;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0.416em -6px 0;
    padding: 1.66em 0.833em;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    background: lightgray;
    border-bottom: none;
}

div#content {
    background: lightgray;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}​
```

and I want to make it look like a navigation menu. However, as it's usual, I want to have the border of the content area covering all but the active tab (in this case, that would be "Dashboard"):

[image]

I already tried to increase z-index but it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain what it is your'e after.

From what I gather you want the border to appear around inactive tabs and have no border separating the active tab from the content. Is that correct?

This is basically don't by tricking the active tab into covering the content border with a border color which matches the content.

[You can see a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/qzr3X/2/)

But you'll need to note the class which is added to the "dashboard" tab. It's that active class which covers the border at the bottom of the tab it's applied to.

I have added some jquery to dynamically alter the borders when you click tabs.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Then the problem was adding "position: relative" and "top: 1px", keeping a "margin: -1px" in ul#tabs li a, but why does it behave like that? It seems as if moving ul#tabs would cover the content section but reducing "ul#tabs li a" bottom margin leads the tabs being covered by the content section.

Comment: Well, you had a z-index with no position property. Z-index does nothing unless there is also a position declaration. That was the bulk of the issue. And if you're going to position the tabs, you must also position the content. Otherwise the content will move down the same distance.